# Adding references of Casablanca Libraries

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, casablanca

I am unable to find the references of `Casablanca` libraries from my `Visual Studio` and from some online source, I need the references of these two libraries, **http_client.h** and **filestream.h**

I am using `Visual Studio 2013`, can someone please tell me from where I can download references of these libraries?

I will be really grateful

Comment: Use Nuget to add the package to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved when I installed VS 2015 enterprise, and now in here I don't need to add any references, just install casablanca packages in your project.